# How to use `repo forall -c <something>` where <something> is a bash alias or function

Tags: linux, bash, repo

I've a folder with many git repos. I'm looking for a way to iterate over all the repos and do some fancy listing with a bash function...

Comment: And `-c` is what?

Comment: `export -f yourfunction` will make it available to children, assuming their shell is actually bash (vs `/bin/sh` being implement by ash/dash/ksh/whatnot). Aliases aren't intended for programmatic use, so they can't be exported in this way... but almost anything you could use an alias for you could do with a function instead.

Comment: @Andrey AFAIK it stands for "command"...

Comment: @DgAn Then I've completely misread the title. It wasn't clear to me where metalanguage ended, and where actual command line input began.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#forall), the argument to `-c` is evaluated by `/bin/sh`, so if you place your fancy function into a file named `functions.sh`, then you could do something like:

```
repo forall -c '. /path/to/functions.sh; myfunction'
```

Assuming that `/bin/sh` on your system is actually Bash, or if not:

```
repo forall -c 'bash -c ". /path/to/functions.sh; myfunction"'
```

Comment: Seems to do the job. Thanks!